# JavaScript convert Array of Array of Objects into Array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, foreach

I need convert Array of Array of Objects into a simple Array of objects using JavaScript

Below i go put the current code with the current output

```
const result = [
  [
    {
      name: '1'
    },
    {
      name: '2'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: '3'
    },
    {
      name: '4'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: '5'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: '6'
    }
  ]
]

const a = result.map(item => {
  return Object.assign({}, ...item)
})


console.log(a)
```

Output of the above code (current and wrong output)

```
[ { "name": "2" }, { "name": "4" }, { "name": "5" }, { "name": "6" } ]
```

The expected and needed output

```
[
  {
    name: '1'
  },
  {
    name: '2'
  },
  {
    name: '3'
  },
  {
    name: '4'
  },
  {
    name: '5'
  },
  {
    name: '6'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Array.prototype.concat to merge the arrays.

[Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```js
const result = [
  [
    {
      name: '1'
    },
    {
      name: '2'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: '3'
    },
    {
      name: '4'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: '5'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: '6'
    }
  ]
]

const b = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], result);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're looking for `flat` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat))

```js
const result = [
  [
    {
      name: '1'
    },
    {
      name: '2'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: '3'
    },
    {
      name: '4'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: '5'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: '6'
    }
  ]
]

const a = result.flat();


console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple and well-supported way to flatten arrays without using `flat` - use `reduce` and `push` (not `concat` for efficiency).

```js
const result = [
  [
    {
      name: '1'
    },
    {
      name: '2'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: '3'
    },
    {
      name: '4'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: '5'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: '6'
    }
  ]
]

const a = result.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc.push(...curr), acc));

console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var result = [
  [
    {
      name: '1'
    },
    {
      name: '2'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: '3'
    },
    {
      name: '4'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: '5'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: '6'
    }
  ]
]

var a = result.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  return (Array.prototype.push.apply(acc, curr), acc);
});

console.log(a);
```

Comment: This is inefficient as `concat` would create a new array every time. A more efficient version would be to `push` elements to `acc`.

Comment: OK @slider I'll change that.

Comment: Fixed @slider, any better?